# Commenting in pycharm

Tags: comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to use the shortcut 'Ctrl + /' to comment a single line but it would just go to the next line, same as pressing the downward arrow key.  I checked up the shortcut by ctrl+shift+A and it seems that the shortcut is ctrl+/. What can I do? I tried remapping the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

To comment a line of code, place the caret at the appropriate line and press Ctrl+/ . To move a line up or down, press Alt+Shift+Up or Alt+Shift+Down respectively.

To reset...

First,
To view the keymap configuration, open the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S) and select Keymap.
Second,
right-click an action and select Reset Shortcuts.

Comment: Yes I did put my caret at the line I wanted to comment and pressed 'ctrl+/' but pressing 'ctrl+/' moved the caret up or down rather then commenting. That was the error I was encountering in the first place

Comment: It seems like the name of file was restricting it to not be a python file (it worked as a regular file) and that's why I wasn't able to run any shortcuts. Thanks for the help regardless